# Error when using colour in \author

Tags: beamer, errors, color, titles

I am getting an error when I try to use `\color{}` in the the author field with `beamer`, even though the file compiles and I get the the words I want coloured in the author field.

This is the error description:

> ERROR: Argument of \beamer@stripands has an extra }.
>
> --- TeX said ---  
>                   \par  l.8 ...\ \small \vspace{1cm} \color{viv} My name}
>
> --- HELP --- From the .log file...
>
> I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything. For
>   example,`\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce this error. If you
>   simply proceed now, the`\par' that I've just inserted will cause me
>   to report a runaway argument that might be the root of the problem.
>   But if your `}' was spurious, just type`2' and it will go away.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{viv}{RGB}{255,109,254}
\title[]{\Large Credit and Banking in a DSGE Model\\ of the Euro Area} 
\author[]{\Large Gerali, Neri, Sessa and Signoretti (2010) \\ \small \vspace{1cm} \color{viv} My name}

\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}  
\end{document}
```

This MWE compiles and gives me the words "My name" coloured as desired. If I get rid of `\color{viv}` I no longer get the error message, but then, I don't get the colouring as I wish.

Does anyone know why I am getting this error message and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a classic instance of needing `\texorpdfstring`, since the material you put in these metadata fields will also be made into PDF bookmarks, which can't have formatting like color.  Here is a fix for you:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{viv}{RGB}{255,109,254}
\title[]{\Large Credit and Banking in a DSGE Model\\ of the Euro Area} 
\author[]{\Large Gerali, Neri, Sessa and Signoretti(2010)\texorpdfstring{\\ \small \vspace{1cm} \color{viv}}{ }My name}

\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}  
\end{document}
```

(`\texorpdfstring` presents two alternatives, the first to be put in the TeX source, the second to be put in the PDF metadata)

Comment: I think the use of `\textcolor` here is also better, since `beamer` treats `\color` differently than it does `\textcolor`. To see this, use `\show\color` and `\show\textcolor`.

Comment: @Werner I am not sure how to use \textcolor here, since if I just substitute \color{viv} by \textcolor{viv} only the first letter of "My name" will be coloured. Can you give me the full line example using \textcolor? And I also don't understand why \textcolor is better...

Comment: @Vivi: You need to use `\textcolor{viv}{My name}`. `\textcolor` takes two arguments. If you don't supply the second argument, then the first character of the next token is taken as the argument. If you use `\textcolor` rather than `\color`, your MWE compiles with only warnings and no error. That led me to look at the definitions of both `\color` and `\textcolor`. The former seems to pass through a `beamer` "inspection", while the latter does not. So, that's why I say using `\textcolor` seems to be an unaltered use, and therefore perhaps preferred.

Comment: @Werner I could swear I had tried to use \textcolor{viv}{My name} before asking this question! I was confused now with the use of \textcolor because in the example Ryan gave "My name" was put outside of \texorpdfstring{}{}, but if using \textcolor it would have to be inside \texorpdfstring{}{}. I just tried though and it doesn't seem to matter whether "My name" goes inside or outside \texorpdfstring. Thanks for pointing out about \textcolor  :)

Comment: @Vivi: Ryan's answer puts the TeX expression inside the "conditional" `\texorpdfstring`. This means that the colour change is decided upon conditionally, and affects everything after it - in your case, "My name". If you were to use `\textcolor`, you would have "My name" in both parts of `\texorpdfstring`. As in `\texorpdfstring{\textcolor{viv}{My name}}{My name}`.