# Error when using \bm in *numbered* section title, when hyperref is loaded

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, errors

I am getting an error when I use the command `\bm` in a section title that is numbered, when the package `hyperref` is loaded. Here is the error:

> ERROR: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
>
> --- TeX said --- to be read again>
>                      { l.10 ...ction{A proof of convexity in  $p,\bm{w}$}

and here is the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}  
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{A proof of convexity in  $p,\bm{w}$}
\end{document}
```

Note that I can get avoid the error if I do any of the following

- use `\section*` instead of `\section` (and this really intrigues me!)
- remove the `\bm{}` from the title
- remove the package `hyperref`

I noticed there is a question similar to mine (such as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22995/14)) but the solution seems not to be related to my problem.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: You don't know how to use backticks?

Comment: @DamienWalters no... I have no idea what you are talking about... Can you explain?

Comment: Inline codes each should be sandwiched by a pair of backticks.

Comment: @DamienWalters oh, I see. Yes, I know that... I thought you were referring to some latex backticking. I should have done that, but forgot. Thanks :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The PDF bookmarks can not have formatting, so you can either

1. Use `\texorpdfstring` within the `\section` command to provide the alternate text to be used for the bookmakrs:

   ```
   \section{A proof of convexity in  \texorpdfstring{$p,\bm{w}$}{$p,w$}}
   ```
2. Or use `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` to disable the macros (thanks to **Stephan Lehmke** for pointing this out):

   ```
   \pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
       \renewcommand*{\bm}[1]{#1}%
       % any other necessary redefinitions 
   }
   ```

   I prefer this approach as it does not clutter up your main text.

---

### Code: `\texorpdfstring`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}  
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \section{A proof of convexity in  \texorpdfstring{$p,\bm{w}$}{$p,w$}}
\end{document}
```

---

### Code: `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}  
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
    \renewcommand*{\bm}[1]{#1}%
    % any other necessary redefinitions 
}

\begin{document}
  \section{A proof of convexity in  $p,\bm{w}$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's the second time the solution to my problem is to use \texorpdfstring{}{}! See my other question related to beamer title here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45938/14  That solves my problem and I am happy, but out of curiosity, do you know why removing the numbering (using \section*) solves the problem?

Comment: I assume that when you use `\section*`, then that section is not only not numbered, but it is also not added to the TOC (unless you use `\phatomsection`), so there is no issue.